# How to Style the Font-family of a data-error

Tags: html, css, validation, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style the data-error that presents itself if you move on without filling the field, but so far havent been able to figure it out.

I was able to style the font family for the placeholder using this:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
}
```

I had attempted to use the same method to style the data-error, but I admit I'm not a pro with CSS, so not sure if its even close to correct:

```
::-webkit-input-data-error {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
}

::-ms-input-data-error {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
}

::-moz-data-error {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
}

::-moz-data-error {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
}
```

This is an html snippet from the section im working on..

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form_name">First Name *</label>
  <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

*****I just applied it to the id of "contact-form", solved! @Balázs Varga, I don't know why I didn't think to do that to begin with. Thank You!

Comment: I checked the boostrap-4 css file and it doesn't contain the above-mentioned CSS classes related to validations. It seems that validation related CSS classes are dynamically generated via the boostrap JS files.

Comment: You should check what is the element's class the error was rendered inside, and style that with css, something like `.error-message` .

Comment: I just applied it to the id of "contact-form", solved! @Balázs Varga, I don't know why I didn't think to do that to begin with. Thank You!